# js code... don't know why i can not get the value from the input

Tags: jquery

The following is the code in my js.

```
    $('.btn btn-default').click(function(){
        var post = $('input:text').val();
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $('input:text').val("");
        $('.count').text('100');
        $('.btn btn-default').addClass('disabled');
    });
```

the following is the code in my html.

```
    <div class= "blank">
        <input type="text" id="form-control" placeholder="Please Leave Comment Here."/>
    </div>
    <div class = "status">
        <div class= "count">100</div>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Post">
    </div>       
    <ul class="posts">
    </ul>
```

Comment: <div class= "blank">
       <input type="text" id="form-control" placeholder="Please Leave Comment Here."/>
       </div>
       
       
       <div class = "status">
       <div class= "count">100</div>
       <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Post">
       </div>
       
       <ul class="posts">
      </ul>

Comment: Should be `$('.btn.btn-default')`, with a period not a space.

Comment: Is your jQuery in a document ready call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector is wrong. It should be `.btn.btn-default`.
If one and the same DOM element has two or more classes, you have to chain the classes like in your case.

If you select `.btn .btn-default`, then the selector searches for child DOM elements of `.btn`. So e.g. you would get the inner div in the following example:

```
<div class="btn">
    <div class="btn-default"></div
</div
```

```
$('.btn.btn-default').click(function(){
    var post = $('input:text').val();
    $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
    $('input:text').val("");
    $('.count').text('100');
    $('.btn.btn-default').addClass('disabled');
});
```

I've also created a fiddle for your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/d6jvsjxb/.

Comment: It , still, doesn't work. Nothing happends when i clickon that post button.

Comment: @David Thomas: I've edited my answer - thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Yuan Huang: I've also created a fiddle now, where you can test my solution. You can find the link above.

Comment: It's worth noting that, with the space and *without a period*, as written in the question, the selector is trying to match a `<btn-default>` element found within an element with a class-name of `btn`.

Comment: @MichaelStork Thanks so much. It works perfect on jsfiddle. but it's so weird that it doesn't work on my local host.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you so much for your explanation.